# Mysql "near" duplicate only with a pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a MySQL query :

To show "near" duplicate rows with : a reference and the same reference + the pattern "-??" ("-" and 2 chars ONLY, "?" is a random char).

Example with a table with id,reference :

```
id reference
1 DGGDL 
2 DGGDL 
3 HSDKH
4 HSDKH-45
5 2KXQF
6 2KXQF
7 2J6SF
8 2J6SF-442
9 FSM
10 148-54
11 148-54
12 148
13 BWZM-67
```

I want a request on this table with exactly this result :

```
 id reference
 3 HSDKH
 4 HSDKH-45
 10 148-54
 12 148
```

2J6SF-442 is not here because the pattern is "-" + 2 char only (442 is 3 char so it doesn't match the pattern).
HSDKH and HSDKH-45 are in the result because HSDKH-45 match "HSDKH-??" and HSDKH exist, BWZM-67 is NOT in the results because it match "BWZM-??" but there is no reference "BWZM" in the table.
All other "duplicates" that dont match the pattern are excluded from the result (like DGGDL because there is no reference like DGGDL-?? in the table).

my table name is **products**, and the simplified structure is :

```
id,reference
```

I tried many different requests without success… that's why I will not post useless request.
I don't know if I am very clear, but the example show exactly what I want.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.col
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col like concat(t.col, '%-__') or
                    t1.col like concat(t2.col, '%-__')
             );
```

If the two characters are specifically numeric:

```
              where t2.col regexp concat(t.col, '-[0-9]{2}$') or
                    t1.col regexp concat(t2.col, '-[0-9]{2}$')
```

Or, if you want the results on one row for each group:

```
select group_concat(t.col)
from t
group by substring_index(t.col, '-', 1)
having sum(t.col like '%-__') > 0 and
       sum(t.col not like '%-__') > 0;
```

Comment: -% mean - + any char, I want two char only, maybe '-__' better ? I try this.

Comment: @neoteknic . . . Yes.

Comment: Ok It'is working, but only on my test table.
On the production table, 26k rows... Way too long (timeout after 2minutes...). reference is indexed, engine is innodb, MariaDB 10.1
Any way to improve performance ?

Comment: @neoteknic . . . Did you try the `group by` query?

Comment: I try it, did'nt have much time yesterday.

Comment: Perfect, the group_concat if very good and FAST (0.05s) the other query is impossible to use because it take more than 10sec (maybe 2 min or more).
Thank you very much !

Comment: I'm just trying to have a good display for the result , something like : 
SELECT p.id,p.reference FROM products p WHERE reference IN (
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(products.reference)
FROM products
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(products.reference, '-', 1)
HAVING SUM(products.reference LIKE '%-__') > 0 AND
       SUM(products.reference NOT LIKE '%-__') > 0))

but not working of course

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for all references that have a counterpart in the same table, where the two references only differ by the last three characters `'-??'`. In `LIKE` the character wildcard is `_`.

The query:

```
select *
from mytable t1
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable t2
  where t1.reference like concat(t2.reference, '-__')
     or t2.reference like concat(t1.reference, '-__')

)
order by reference;
```

Comment: Trying this buy very long and timeout in PMA. I will try on a test table ! 26k rows. reference is in index. Same answer than @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Maybe `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` is set to a low value. If so remove that restriction: `SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=0;`.

Comment: Yes but inusable in production, I need a faster query (less than 10s). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach: Add a computed column to the table holding the reference minus the trailing '-??'. Then create an index on that column.

```
alter table mytable add column refshaved varchar(20) generated always as 
  (case when reference like '%-__' 
        then left(reference, length(reference)-3) 
        else reference end) stored;

create index idx on mytable(refshaved, reference);

select *
from mytable t1
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable t2
  where t2.refshaved =  t1.refshaved
    and t2.reference <> t1.reference
)
order by reference;
```

Rextester demo: https://rextester.com/OLHJ35843

Comment: Seems to be good, but you have to alter the table and add an index. I prefer the group_concat way, very fast (56ms) on big table and no need to alter the table. Thank you. Good answer too !